# forms and reports 11g R2 installation issue (checking operating system certification status failed)

Tags: oracle11g

i was trying to install forms and report 11g R2 version . while checking prerequisite check it is unsuccessful. i have checked the version value ="6.1" entry is already available but still prerequisite check is failed . Can some one help?

Comment: I am facing the same problem have you got any solution ?

Comment: this may be help you http://theheat.dk/blog/?p=1983

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines in your refhost.xml file located at 
`C:\Users\Abdullah_9795\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2015-09-04_12-37-56PM\prereq`

```
<OPERATING_SYSTEM>
  <VERSION VALUE="6.1"/>
</OPERATING_SYSTEM>
<OPERATING_SYSTEM>
  <VERSION VALUE="6.2"/>
</OPERATING_SYSTEM>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Find below path

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2017-XX-DD_HH-MM-12AM\prereq\win64\refhost.xml
```

win64  will change based on your OS.

**Step 2**: Find your current OS version, eg : 10.0.02.0

Pick first 3 digits, i.e. 10.0,
add  line under `<CERTIFIED_SYSTEMS>` tag on `refhost.xml`  file

```
<OPERATING_SYSTEM>
   <VERSION VALUE="10.0"/>
</OPERATING_SYSTEM>
```

**Step 3**: click back on your installation wizard, then proceed.

This issue I found during OSB installation and fixed.